# Please help me convert this C# 2.0 snippet to Linq

Tags: c#-3.0, performance, c#-2.0, linq-to-objects, readability

This is not a homework ;)
I need to both A) optimize the following code (between a TODO and a ~TODO) and B) convert it to [P]Linq. Better readability is desired. It might make sense to provide answers to A) and B) separately. Thanks!

```
lock (Status.LockObj)
{
    // TODO: find a better way to merge these dictionaries
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, Message> sInstance in newSInstanceDictionary)
    {
        this.sInstanceDictionary.Add(sInstance.Key, sInstance.Value);
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, Message> sOperation in newSOperationDictionary)
    {
        this.sOperationDictionary.Add(sOperation.Key, sOperation.Value);
    }
    // ~TODO
}
```

P.S. Check out my other, bounty question.

Comment: What is leading you to a need to optimise this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358229%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) operator:

```
 return newSInstanceDictionary.Union(newSOperationDictionary).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

Comment: That won't return a dictionary.

Comment: @SLaks - Added `ToDictionary` call.

Answer (score 1):

There are no LINQ methods that would help you here, although you could make your own extension methods.

If the dictionaries are empty before this code runs, you could call `ToDictionary`.